# Django: Parameters in URLs .... which start with a slash

Tags: django, django-urls

I use a regex for URL dispatching like described in the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/urls/#using-regular-expressions).

```
r'^remote/(?P<slug>[^/]+)/call_rfc/(?P<rfc_name>.+)$'
```

Unfortunately rfc_name can start with a slash!

Example:

```
https://example.com/remote/my_slug/call_rfc//MLK/FOO
```

The rfc_name is `/MLK/FOO`.

But this fails. Somewhere (I don't know yet if it is in the browser or in Django) the duplicate slash gets removed.

What is the best practice to handle URL parameters which can start with a slash?

Answer (score 1):

It almost seems that you can consider the latest "slug" as a path. If that's the case, in your URL definition you can use `path` to represent that. You can have a look [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/urls/#path-converters) to check if it helps.

```py
path('remote/<slug:slug>/call_rfc/<path:rfc_name>', yourviewhere)
```

Or, you can perhaps write your [custom path converter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/urls/#registering-custom-path-converters).